# Can I publish an app to the AppStore while having iOS 9 beta installed on my iPhone and using Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Prior to submit an app to the AppStore we must generate an Archive, and have an iPhone or an iPad connected to Xcode during that time.

If I upgrade to the iOS 9 beta, will I still be able to do this (generate the archive from Xcode 6)? Or will I encounter any issues if I upgrade?

Thank you!

Comment: Will you still be able to do _what_, exactly? What does an archive have to do with connecting your device to Xcode? This question makes no sense. And your title involves something else entirely, namely publishing to the App Store. Do you even know what you want to know?

Comment: I didn't ask if I was able to publish an app with Xcode beta. I asked if I could still generate an archive with an iPhone connected to xcode that runs a beta (iOS9), only to be able to generate the archive. It's a valid, honest question. Why the down vote?

Comment: "I didn't ask if I was able to publish an app with Xcode beta" Yes you did. The title of your question is "Can I publish an app to the AppStore".

Comment: Read again please.... "Can I publish an app to the AppStore -> while <- having iOS 9 beta installed on my iPhone?" I also have developed the question. It's right bellow. I will update to better reflect the question.

Comment: And I pointed out that the two things are unrelated. The iTunes Connect upload process knows nothing of what's on your iPhone! You keep saying the same thing but not listening to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install two (or more) versions of Xcode on your Mac, beta versions of Xcode for testing, and the official released version for App Store build and submission purposes. Currently, for instance, install Xcode-beta 7.x to directly run and debug test builds on an iPhone running an iOS 9 beta, and install Xcode 6.x to build with the iOS 8 SDK and submit to the App Store.  You can (and should) also still test the latter build using Ad Hoc deployment.

Comment: Xcode versions on your Mac +1 ///  Ad Hoc deployment. +1 .

Answer (score 1):

Dont do that ! It is risky.

> XCode cannot run an app into your iPhone/iPad, if the iPhone OS version is greater than the higher iOS version in XCode.
>   It is risky. If you install *iOS 9 bêta* on iPhone, and XCode has only *iOS 8.3*, you wont be able to run an app from XCode--to-->iPhone
>   Ok running is not publishing.
>   But you know Apple/XCode... So strict, minimize the risk. Dont do that.
>   Beta is NOT for publishing & public releases.

Comment: That makes sense. My question is, will I be able to generate the archive? I'm not looking to run the app. Only to generate the archive from Xcode 6.